# Overpass-API request does not get executed completely : particular results lead to mistakes

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have some issues with the following request via [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu). Only the last expression works. In other words, only the very last expression will be performed and all the others are ignored.

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,::lon,::lat,amenity,name,"addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","contact:website",website,"contact:email")]
[timeout:600];
rel[boundary=administrative][admin_level=6][name="München"] -> .city;
(nwr[amenity=hospital][name](around.city:2000);
nwr[amenity=school][name](around.city:2000););
nwr[amenity=childcare][name](around.city:2000);
nwr[amenity=kindergarten][name](around.city:2000);
nwr[amenity=nursing_home][name](around.city:2000);
nwr[amenity=college][name](around.city:2000);

out center;
```

In fact only this term will be executed:

```
nwr[amenity=college][name](around.city:2000);
```

This is given back:

```
@id @type   @lon    @lat    amenity name    addr:postcode   addr:city   addr:street addr:housenumber    contact:website website contact:email
2354666181  node    11.5557656  48.1274889  college EAM-Europa Akademie München - School Of International Business  80337   München Adlzreiterstraße    6           
3324407853  node    11.5551400  48.1264588  college Akademie Deutsche POP   80337   München Adlzreiterstraße    18a     http://www.deutsche-pop.de/standort/muenchen    
3324407854  node    11.5713030  48.1285751  college Akademie Deutsche POP   80469   München Klenzestraße    67      http://www.deutsche-pop.de/standort/muenchen    
4379246720  node    11.5629942  48.1469822  college Hochschule für Politik München  80333   München Richard-Wagner-Straße   1           
4448465264  node    11.4461165  48.1488143  college DEKRA Akademie GmbH                     https://www.dekra-akademie.de/de/muenchen/  
4984543723  node    11.5998193  48.1353510  college Münchner Volkshochschule – Einstein 28  81675   München Einsteinstraße  28      https://www.mvhs.de/ueber-uns/standorte/gasteig-einstein-28-stadtbereich-mitte/ 
5542020160  node    11.6368555  48.0790856  college Fakultät für Betriebswirtschaftf                            
5542020161  node    11.6348063  48.0806016  college Fakultät für Betriebswirtschaft                         
5542020162  node    11.6336959  48.0810352  college Fakultät für Betriebswirtschaft                         
18940172    way 11.4648639  48.1127381  college Haus A Genzentrum der LMU und Institut für Biochemie    81377   München Feodor-Lynen-Straße 25      https://www.genzentrum.lmu.de/  
19329687    way 11.5817581  48.1500346  college Herzogliches Georgianum 80539   München Professor-Huber-Platz   1       http://www.herzoglichesgeorgianum.de/Herzogliches_Georgianum/Home.html  
27959435    way 11.5929977  48.1424114  college Bayerische EliteAkademie    80538   München Prinzregentenstraße 7       http://www.eliteakademie.de 
44615795    way 11.5806579  48.1550310  college Priesterseminar St. Johannes der Täufer                 http://www.priesterseminar-muenchen.de/     
166433609   way 11.5888108  48.1304498  college Collegium Carolinum                         
867729755   way 11.6027411  48.1324959  college Katholische Stiftungshochschule München                     https://www.ksh-muenchen.de
```

Well I wonder if there must be missing something in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following request works for me. I basically only changed the position of the brackets.

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,::lon,::lat,amenity,name,"addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","contact:website",website,"contact:email")]
    [timeout:600];
    rel[boundary=administrative][admin_level=6][name="München"] -> .city;
    (
    nwr[amenity=hospital][name](around.city:200);
    nwr[amenity=school][name](around.city:200);
    nwr[amenity=childcare][name](around.city:200);
    nwr[amenity=kindergarten][name](around.city:200);
    nwr[amenity=nursing_home][name](around.city:200);
    nwr[amenity=college][name](around.city:200);
    );
    
    out center;
```

Comment: hello dear 'Nil - many many thanks for the quick help - i am very glad. _Have a great day